# ¿Es mejor ingeniería inversa o crear las entidades con Symfony?

Tags: mvc, symfony2, orm, doctrine2, ingeniería-inversa

Cuando creo mis entidades utilizo la **ingeniería inversa**. Es decir, cojo de la base de datos y symfony genera las entidades mediante estos **comandos**:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle --env=local --em=entityManager (Generate metadata from database, add to em the table in db )

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src --env=local --em=entityManager  (Use the metadata files to generate entities)

php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Producto --env=local (Add setters and getters of atributtes from each entity)
```

Consigue mappear y crearme una *entidad igual que el objeto de la base de datos.*

Mi pregunta es: Si no necesito mapear la base de datos, puedo **crear** la **entidad desde symfony** y llevarme esa estructura a la base de datos en un SQL o XML.... ya sea mysql, oracle, mongo...

Comment: Desde mi experiencia, siempre es mejor crear las migraciones a mano y no usar script para generarlas a partir de bases de datos ya creadas.
La razón es simple, si haces algo que se salga de lo común el script puede que lo interprete de otra manera a la que tu la tienes creada y al final el migrate que te crea no sera el correcto, por lo tanto si nos quitamos el paso de de migrar "DB" a "migratrions" nos quitamos un paso entero y por tanto eliminamos posibles errores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues depende, si se trata de un conjunto de datos ya creado, por alguna razón, lo apropiado es dejar que doctrine genera las entidades a partir de las estructuras existentes. Si se trata de generar nuevos conjuntos, o modificar los existentes, entonces genera o modifica las entidades afectadas y luego ejecutas las herramientas oportunas. No existe opción correcta, siempre hay que analizar cada caso.